# how to generate a service by console in symfony2

Tags: symfony, service, console, bundle

I have used a console command like generate:service in symfony,to create service and update the services.yml file.

I install some papular bundle in symfony, it's may have this command.

but i can't find this command now.

did some one tell me which bundle have this command.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a tool, library or resource.

Answer (score 1):

There is no preapred dedicated method or command to do that. You need to create a class and configure it as a service by a hand, but... it's a good idea for a new feature. I'll develop it and push a pull request to Symfony2 repository, so maybe it'll be ready with 2.6 version.